# php not recognizing bind parameter in query when there are more than one parameters present

Tags: php, mysqli

So I cannot figure out where the issue lies as if I bind only one of the parameters, it works. If both are present then it gives me

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement`and produces no output.

It seems not to recognize the second parameter in the where clause. If someone could help me out with this, thank you! The query works if I replace the ? and run in phpMyAdmin. The CNIC is supposed to be a post value and is hard coded for testing purposes.

```
$sql = "SELECT c.cnic, c.name, c.cell_phone, c.address 
        FROM cheetay_customers as c 
            INNER JOIN policies as p ON c.CNIC = p.cnic WHERE `c`.`CNIC`= ? 
                AND `p`.`partnerName`= ?";

if($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) { 
    $cnic = 1267890;
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $cnic);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['access']);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($cnic, $name,$cell_phone,$address);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "CNIC: {$cnic}, Name: {$name}, Cell Phone: {$cell_phone}, Address: {$address}";
    }

} else {
    $error = $con->errno . ' ' . $con->error;
    echo $error; 
}
```

Comment: Side note: If you are building something new, try to switch to PDO to save yourself a lot of coding and headaches ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `bind_param` once and pass it all the parameters in one go

```
 $stmt->bind_param("is", $cnic, $_SESSION['access']);
```